# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: al intentar instalar una librería en VS Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-2.x, blockchain

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error al intentar instalar una librería. Tengo instalada una versión de Python superior a la requerida por la librería, luego no se que problema hay. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lait it\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] 
= '"'"'C:\\Users\\Lait It\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a28yz1o5\\pysha3_904d58dde2634b5cbb23cf3c039d97db\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Lait It\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a28yz1o5\\pysha3_904d58dde2634b5cbb23cf3c039d97db\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Lait It\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v_m2yjjx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\lait it\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pysha3'
         cwd: C:\Users\Lait It\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a28yz1o5\pysha3_904d58dde2634b5cbb23cf3c039d97db\
    Complete output (9 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    copying sha3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
    running build_ext
    building '_pysha3' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\lait it\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Lait It\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a28yz1o5\\pysha3_904d58dde2634b5cbb23cf3c039d97db\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Lait It\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-a28yz1o5\\pysha3_904d58dde2634b5cbb23cf3c039d97db\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Lait It\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v_m2yjjx\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\lait it\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pysha3' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Si le haces caso al error, te dice que te hace falta el Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0. Probaste con instalarlo? El error te ofrece una pagina donde lo puedes descargar. Igual no estoy muy seguro de que haya que descargar, ya que parece que la pagina te ofrece un ide.

Answer (score 0):

Esa librería lleva sin actualizarse desde 2017. Te aconsejaría que usases otra que si tenga un mantenimiento activo. A pesar de eso yo tampoco puedo instalarla en un entorno virtual a pesar de tener los build-tools.

```
\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
```

El problema es que esa librería no tiene un paquete pip precompilado así que espera que tu lo compiles en tu equipo, pero sin las herramientas necesaria y la configuración no vas a poder. Si encuentro la solución actualizo esta respuesta, pero por el momento te aconsejaria que buscases una alternativa más actualizada.